# Mudar Resposta JSON no php

Tags: php, json

Ola amigos preciso mudar a resposta em json mas nao estou conseguindo. segue:

```
    $ch       = curl_init('http://sams-api.arar.local/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'phone_number=' . $phoneNumber . '&message=' . 'Ola sua Senha no Painel do Assinante da Mar Telecom e: '.$senha_gerada);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);


    echo($_SESSION['contrato_recupera']['CL_Sms']);
        die;


            $.ajax({ url: 'carregaDados.php',
                data: {function2call: 'buscaContrato', contrato: $("#contratos_vinculados").val()},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(output) 
                {
                    var dados = JSON.parse(output);

                //console.log(output);
                $("#celularRecupera").text(dados[0].telefone);

                }
            });

        });

          function recuperaSenha()
        {
            $("#recuperaBtn").hide();
            $.ajax({ url: 'carregaDados.php',
                data: {function2call: 'criaSenha'},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(output) 
                {

                alert('Senha enviada por SMS para '+output ); window.location.href = 'entrar.php';
```

a resposta vem da seguinte forma:

```
            Senha enviada por SMS para {"error":false,"message":"Message sent","data":[]}22996058462
```

Como eu faço para tirar esse {"error":false,"message":"Message sent","data":...  ???  alguem ajuda ?

Comment: Seu php está misturado com javascript ou são 2 caras diferentes?

Answer (score -1):

Pode usar uma expressão regular em um replace:

```
{.+}  // irá selecionar tudo que tiver entre as chaves (inclusive as chaves)
```

Exemplo:

```js
output = 'Senha enviada por SMS para {"error":false,"message":"Message sent","data":[]}22996058462';
output = output.replace(/{.+}/, '');
console.log(output);
```